# How to notify when device is out of default set path in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

How to notify when going in the wrong direction in Android GPS programatically. I have a path set default. When the user move's out of that path (say + or - 100 meters towards right or left) it should notify user. Thank you in Advance

Comment: What have **you** tried?

Comment: i tried to use addproximityalerts but i fail in that. now i'm able to draw the path, device should move in that path only. If the device changes its path it should give a alert or notification something like that

Answer (score 2):

You could always check distance between points in your set path and the actual location using euclidean geometry. Although if accuracy were to worsen you will get false positives. Since GPS Location provides coordinates it gets a little more complicated than this. But check out this site:

[Calculate distance between two points on a globe](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe#Java)

Note: You would have to slightly modify that code.